# Android Libgdx assetManager: asset not loaded

Tags: java, android, libgdx, loading, assets

I am having a weird issue with just loading my assets, using the assetManager. My assetManager is a separate class I made to make everything shorter and more neat. My Asset class isn't static. I have all the assets loaded in a non static assetDescriptor.

I load my splash screen which in tern loads all my assets while that is displaying. when I call the other screen the assets I have loaded can not be loaded and causes my game to crash. The splash screen does load but when it assigns a new screen it crashes.

I have spent 2 days on this issue. trying more then 15 variations. To no prevail.

**My error message is:**

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: stuff.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:144)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:167)
    at com.nectar.pewdybird.mainMenu.<init>(mainMenu.java:71)
    at com.nectar.pewdybird.pewdyBird.render(pewdyBird.java:68)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

**Splash.class:**

```
public Assets assets;

public void create(){
   assets = new Assets();
   assets.load();
}

public void render(){
   if(assets.update()) {
        setScreen(new mainMenu(this));
        dispose();
    } else {
        //Splash Screen
        gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        //Draws SplashScreen
        batch.end();
    }
}

public void dispose(){
    this.screen.dispose();
    this.batch.dispose();
}
```

**mainMenu.class**

```
public Assets assets;
private Texture Stuff;    

public mainMenu(Splash game){
     assets = game.assets;
     Stuff = game.assets.manager.get(game.assets.stuff);


}
```

**Asset.class**

```
 public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(new InternalFileHandleResolver());

public final AssetDescriptor<Texture> stuff =
        new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("stuff.png", Texture.class);

 public void load(){
    manager.load(stuff);
    //12 More loads
    manager.finishLoading();

}

public boolean update(){
    return manager.update();
}
```

Thank you for reading and possibly helping with my maybe simple issue.

Comment: 1. Splash class implements Screen or extends Game class. ? 2. You're using parameterised constructor of mainMenu, where it is ?

Comment: Splash extends com.badlogic.gdx.game;
and mainMenu implements Screen. and the mainMenu

should I make the splash implement screen aswell? I just figured that I am not actually using gdx.game in my splash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `mainMenu` class. You're creating a new `Assets` object, that don't have any asset so instead of creating a new `Assets` object use Assets object of `Splash` because you loaded assets on that object.

```
public Assets assets;
public Texture Stuff;

public mainMenu(){
     assets = new Assets();  // why are you creating new Assets here
     Stuff = assets.manager.get(assets.stuff);
}
```

Actually you're creating object of `mainMenu` by using parameterised constructor in `Splash` class

```
public mainMenu(Splash splash){
     assets = splash.assets;  // instead of creating new take reference of Splash class assets
     Stuff = assets.manager.get(assets.stuff);
}
```

Comment: I have changed my Assets object in mainMenu to "public Assets assets = game.assets;" and my mainMenu method looks like this public mainMenu(Splash game). It is not fixing the problem. its the same.

Comment: what you edited in your code please edit here in your question so that I can further find your bug .

Comment: I will do that for now on. my apology's.

Comment: I don't think so exception are same not you're getting some other exception ? check your exception ?

Comment: don't call `dispose();` in render method of your `Splash` class.

Comment: getting rid of the dispose has made my game stop crashing, Thank you! But now nothing is displaying and I guess that is up for another question if I can not find it out. Thank you for your input.